# Serving static assets offline, cache policy in Angular Univeral

Tags: angular, caching, angular-universal

My service worker isn't caching my static assets.

When online, using Chrome DevTools it looks like ServiceWorker is working. I see rows for styles.xxx.css, runtime.xxx.js, polyfills.xxx.js and main.xxx.js with the Size listed as "from Service Worker". Then in later rows, these same files are listed with Size as "from disk cache".[image]

Under the Chrome DevTools Application tab, Cache Storage section I have the following rows:

ngsw:db:control - http://127.0.0.1:8080

ngsw:xxx:assets:app:cache - http://127.0.0.1:8080

ngsw:xxx:assets:app:meta - http://127.0.0.1:8080

Clicking on the last two rows results in nothing in the "Path" section of DevTools.

The ngws-worker.js has an "activated and is running" status. It was "Received 12/31/1969" which is odd.

Then when I go offline, no Service Workers are shown. And the Cache Storage is empty.The last network row says ngsw.json?ngsw-cache-bust=xxx Status (failed) Type fetch Initiator ngsw-worker.js:2662.

My package.json scripts are (which I copied from AngularFirebasePro) are

```
"webpack:prerender": "webpack --config webpack.prerender.config.js",
"build:prerender": "node dist/abogado/prerender.js",
"serve:prerender": "http-server dist/abogado -o",
"build:all": "ng build --prod && ng run abogado:server && npm run 
webpack:prerender && npm run build:prerender"
```

In angular.json I have

```
"server": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/abogado-server",
        "main": "src/main.server.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

my ngsw-config.json file is

```
{
 "index": "/index.html",
 "assetGroups": [{
   "name": "app",
   "installMode": "prefetch",
   "resources": {
     "files": [
       "/index.html"
     ],
     "versionedFiles": [
       "/*.bundle.css",
       "/*.bundle.js",
       "/*.chunk.js"
     ]
  }
 }, {
   "name": "assets",
   "installMode": "lazy",
   "updateMode": "prefetch",
   "resources": {
     "files": [
       "/assets/**"
     ]
   }
 }]
```

}

Once I build my app, my dist folder does contain ngsw.json and ngws-worker.js.

I don't know NodeJS.
First, I'd like to know if caching static assets is possible in Angular Universal. Second, what do you think is wrong with my code?
Thank you : )

EDIT: adding main.ts file contents.

```
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .then(() => {
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/ngsw-worker.js') ;
      }
    })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the version of Angular involved, this is most likely related to this bug:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20360

There are many work arounds posted in that issue page. If you cannot get those to work, the next (very good) alternative is to migrate your app to the [Angular Universal PWA Starter project](https://github.com/bellizio/angular-universal-pwa).

The final alternative is to use the [Workbox CLI](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-cli) directly. This is what is used in the PWA Starter Project.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I check for the serviceWorker in the navigator in my main.ts file. Adding code up above. I'm still going through the possible fixes from the issue page. However, that issue has the page crash. And my page doesn't crash,  it just can't get to the files.

Comment: OK, forget the Angular issue then. Have you tried implementing Workbox? Or thought about migrating to the starter kit for PWA? Those WILL work unless you have something in your Angular application that is not coded properly.

Comment: That Angular Universal PWA Starter project is in Angular 5. I'm using Angular 7 now. So, I'm not sure. I also use prerendering, so it would be a lot of code that I would have to copy into the new project.

Comment: I don't know much about the Workbox CLI, I find it difficult to believe that I need it just to get a ServiceWorker to work properly. I don't want to just throw on more stuff on top of this black box. But if it comes to it, I will.

Comment: Put up a StackBlitz of your entire project or a GitHub repo of it. I'll take a look.

Comment: I just made it public on github https://github.com/flocela/Maldonado-abogado.git  The branch is cachePro

Comment: Is that good enough, sorry I don't have experience on StackBlitz. But I can figure it out.

Comment: Actually now it has a different problem, it can't find @angular/service-worker in app.module. Sorry. I've been adding things from npm this morning. However, I didn't commit any changes to my git repository, so I'm not sure why it would have a problem now. I'll work on it.

Comment: Okay, it's running now. I'm not sure what the problem was. I pushed it up to github on branch cachePro, but it said there was nothing to commit, so the one on github cachePro does run, but doesn't cache files.

Comment: Hi again. Here it is on Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/github/flocela/Maldonado-abogado/tree/cachePro

Comment: So I finally got a chance to look into you GitHub repo. A major part of your problem stems from most of your images coming from you FireBase server. When accessing those images from CSS `background-image` work fine (normal page load), but FireBase has no CORS headers, so when accessing those files to cache them via AJAX, CORS errors are thrown for all of them. I suspect the same is happening with  the FaceBook resources you are using too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190178/discussion-between-flobacca-and-randy-casburn).